# How Can I Re-write My While Loop into Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop, iteration

How can I write my following code so it does not iterate but use **recursion** instead (i.e. remove the while loop):

```
public static void addSlashes(String str)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (str.length() != 0){
         while (i < str.length()){
              // get character at current 'i' index of string,
              // then adds a "/" after it:
              System.out.print(str.charAt(i) + "/");
              i++;
         }
}
```

Would the while loop in this case be **recursive** or **iterative**?  I'm thinking it'd be iterative because it repeats again and again for the length of the string in the parameter.

An example output using this method may be:

```
addSlashes("Hello");

H/e/l/l/o
```

Comment: it will print H/e/l/l/o/

Comment: Hint: to make it recursive, you will have to always use first character of the argument string in actual method body.

Comment: Why are you interested in it. Why do you do this check: `if (str.length() != 0)` ?

Comment: @Wolf I just put that line of code to check if there's actually a string passed in the parameter or if it's an empty string (i.e. " ");

Comment: If the string is "", the while block will never be executed as 0 is not smaller than 0 and `i` is 0

Comment: What should this `print` be? `public`?

Comment: Oh whoops, yes it should be public.  It's a typo, sorry about that...

Comment: NB: while you _could_ write this function recursively, you shouldn't, because repeatedly taking substrings is an inefficient operation.   It is _way_ better to just iterate over the characters.

Comment: By the way, the snippet `if (str.length() != 0)` can be removed; it's redundant. Oh, wait. Dozens of people already mentioned that. Well, just confirming.

Comment: alternatively you could use replaceAll method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `substring` and with only a `String` parameter:

```
public static void addSlashes(String str) {
    if (str.isEmpty())
        return;

    System.out.print(str.charAt(0) + "/");
    addSlashes(str.substring(1));
}
```

Note that it's a rather inefficient approach, as it will actually create `length` `String` instances in most Java runtimes.

Run it [here](https://repl.it/F9os).

Comment: Thanks so much -- the link you provided helped me to understand how it actually works so I chose your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to break the task into parts

- slash insertion
- output

The output part you already know if you are able to write a hello-world program in Java (which seems to be the case).

Here is the slashing part, isolated from output.

```
public static String slashed(String s) {
    if (s.length() > 0){
        return s.charAt(0)+"/"+slashed(s.substring(1));
    }
    return s;
}
```

It takes a string and adds slashes after each single char (in a recursive) way. Running example is here: http://ideone.com/YUrGMy

### Disclaimer

**You** were asking for a recursive String-based solution. But it's not efficient to build strings this way, also if you use the slightly more efficient iteration method. Both are allocating and moving memory needlessly. If you are interested in a real-world solution for tasks like this, have a look on Java's [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) class.

Comment: One could argue that the `isEmpty()` method should be preferred, but I'm unsure about this, taking `length()` into account (visually) illustrates that there we process a string in all its length...

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public static void addSlashes(String str, int len) {
     if(len < str.length()) {
         System.out.print(str.charAt(len) + "/");
         addSlashes(str, len +1);
     }
}
```

invoke like:-

```
addSlashes("hello", 0);
```

Sample output

```
h/e/l/l/o/
```

Comment: Can it be done using only one parameter (String str)?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    addSlashes("Hello");
    System.out.println("\n");
    addSlashRecursive("Hello");
}

static void addSlashes(String str) {
    int i = 0;

    if (str.length() != 0) {
        while (i < str.length()) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i) + "/");
            i++;
        }
    }
}

static void addSlashRecursive(String s){
    addSlashRecursive(s, 0);
}

static void addSlashRecursive(String s, int pos){
    System.out.print(s.charAt(pos)+"/");
    if(pos != s.length()-1){
        addSlashRecursive(s, pos+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void addSlashes(String str) {
    System.out.println(str.charAt(0) + "/");
    int length = str.length();
    int i = 1;
    if (length > i) {
        str = str.substring(i, str.length());
        addSlashes(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `i` variable seems to be a bit redundant.

Comment: yeah,such is the case;